# How can i block the possibility to create instance of the base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Is it possible to not allow creating the instance of the base class?

For example i have:

```
class A
{

// code

}
class B : A
{

// code

}
```

And I want to make somehow this behaviour:

```
A baseClass = new A(); // not possible
B derivedClass = new B(); // ok
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to not allow creating the instance of the base class?

Sure, make it [`abstract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx):

```
public abstract class A
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I'll accept Your response in these few minutes.